# I need to replace some words using regex (Address) C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, expression

I need to replace the following words:
**"R " TO "RUA "**, 
**"R. " To "RUA "**, 
**"AV:" TO "AVENIDA "**

Ex:
"Jardim test R. paraná" = "Jardim test Rua paraná"
"R. paraná" = "Rua paraná"
"R xavier" = "Rua xavier"

I tried the following expression but it doesn't work:

````
string pattern = @"\bR\.\b";
string replace = "RUA";
logradouro = Regex.Replace(logradouro, pattern, replace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);```
````

Comment: I can't use the replace function:
.Replace ("R ", "Rua ")
"R Xavier" => "Rua Xavierua" error

Comment: Is it possible your string could contain more than one word, for example: `Jardim test R. paraná R`?

Comment: contain only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dictionary with search and replace values, you can build a regex dynamically from the search strings and use the regex to find the terms in the string and use the corresponding values to replace with.

Assuming the keys always start with a word char, here is a dynamic way to handle terms with variable endings:

```cs
public static string CreateWb(string term)
{
    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(term[term.Length-1]) || term[term.Length-1] == '_')
    {
        return $@"\b{Regex.Escape(term)}\b";
    }
    else
    {
        return $@"\b{Regex.Escape(term)}";
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```cs
var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dct.Add("R", "RUA");
dct.Add("R.", "RUA");
dct.Add("AV:", "AVENIDA");
var pat = $@"({string.Join("|", dct.Keys.Select(k => CreateWb(k)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))})\W*(\w)?";
var input ="Jardim test R. paraná R. paraná R xavier AV:test AV:VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pat, m => 
        $"{dct[m.Groups[1].Value]}" + (m.Groups[2].Success ? $" {m.Groups[2].Value}" : ""), 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
Console.WriteLine(output);
// => Jardim test RUA paraná RUA paraná RUA xavier AVENIDA test AVENIDA VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ciqlMl)

Note the `\W*(\w)?` at the end of the `(?:term_regex_1|term_regex_2|term_regex_N)\W*(\w)?` regex matches zero or more non-word chars and then matches an optional word char capturing it into Group 2. In the match evaluator part, we check if Group 2 matched, and if yes, the space and this word char are appended to the replace result (which is the dictionary value with Group 1 key), else, just the dictionary value with Group 1 key is returned.

Comment: @RenathuCazari Note I wrote this on an assumption the search strings will always be followed by a non-word char. If `AV:` or `R.` can be glued to the next word (like `AV:WORD`) this solution will need an update. Just let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Yes it can occur
Ex: Av:test => "Avenida test"

Comment: @RenathuCazari Check it now. Note I assume the search terms always start with a word char. The space is added after a match if the next char is a word char, else, no space is added.

Comment: Error: "AV:VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO" --> "AVENIDA:VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO"

Comment: @RenathuCazari What is the error? It works as you expect. If you want to replace `AV:` with `AVENIDA:`, just add this as replacement, with `:`. See https://ideone.com/ciqlMl

Comment: Looking at your test:
Input:
var input ="Jardim test R. paraná R. paraná R xavier AV:test AV:VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO";
Output:
"Jardim test RUA. paraná RUA. paraná RUA xavier AVENIDA:test AVENIDA:VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO"
Correct:
"Jardim test RUA paraná RUA paraná RUA xavier AVENIDA test AVENIDA VEREADOR HOMERO FRANCO"

The . and the : it has to disappear

Comment: @RenathuCazari Ok, so I deduce the following rules: the space must be added if the search term is glued to a word, and any punctuation must be removed. Try [this solution](https://ideone.com/ciqlMl), if it works, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One can use a `MatchEvaluator` with named match groups in the replace such as:

```
Regex.Replace("Jardim test R. av: paraná",
              @"\b((?<Rua>[Rr.]+)|(?<Avienda>[AaVv:]{2,3}))",
              m => { return m.Groups["Avienda"].Success ? "AVIENIDA" : "RUA";});
```

Which the result is `Jardim test RUA AVIENIDA paraná`;